# Show that $X$ has an exponential distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

The exersice is given as it follows:
Let $X$ a random variable with values in $(0, \infty)$ such that for all $x,y > 0$ then $$\mathbb{P}(X \geq x + y | X \geq x) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq y) \dots (*) $$ Show that exist some $\lambda > 0$ such that $X\sim exp(\lambda)$

As an attempt of proof: 
Let $G(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq x)$ a monotonically non-increasing, continuous to the right, and it satisfies: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}G(x) = 0 \text{ } \lim_{x\rightarrow (- \infty)}G(x) = 1 $$

So $(*)$ could be expressed by $$G(x+y)=G(x)G(y) \dots (1)$$ So by some calculus properties we know that $G(n) = [G(1)]^n$ then if $G(1) = 1 \implies \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} G(n) = 1$ which stands a contradiction. By the other hand if $G(\frac{1}{n}) = [G(1)]^{\frac{1}{n}}$ so if $G(1) = 0 \implies \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} G(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$ which is another contradiction (why?). So we know that a $\lambda > 0$ such that $G(1) = e^{-\lambda}$ (remembering another property of calculus if $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ so $f = exp$, anyway I don't understand why at all). Later we take some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and make some inequalities with sequences which is lead to the Distribution $F(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda}$.

So, my doubt is basically to have more details about this proof.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{P}(X>0)=1$ then $G(1/n) \to 1$ which gives the contradiction. For the other see the cauchy functional for details, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation , which you can apply by taking log, i.e., $\log f(x+y) = \log f(x) +\log f(y)$.

Comment: Note that $G(1)=1$ implies that $X$ has no mass on $[0,1]$, which contradicts the assumption that $X$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:[0,\infty) \to g:[0,\infty)$ be non-increasing and suppose $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$. Then $g(nx)=(g(x))^{n}$. also gives $g(\frac n m x)=(g(x))^{\frac n m}$ since both sides have the same $m-$ th power. Thus $g(rx)=(g(x)^{r}$ for all positive rational numbers $r$. Now if $0<r<y$ and $r$ is rational then $g(rx) \geq g(xy)$ so $g(xy) \leq (g(x))^{r}$, Letting $r$ increase to $y$ we get $g(xy) \geq (g(x)^{y}$. Similarly (using rationals greater the $y$ decreasing to $y$) we get $g(xy) \leq (g(x)^{y}$.  We have proved that $g(xy) = (g(x))^{y}$ for all $x,y$. Put $y=\frac 1 x$ to get $g(1)=(g(x))^{1/x}$ or $g(x)=c^{x}$ where $c =g(1)$.